# Confusion about REST API calls

Tags: rest

I have an api gateway installed that I'm trying to program against. Requests work when using apps like Postman but when I try to connect through code in the form of XMLHTTPRequests I get `401`... `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` saying that the server doesn't allow cross site calls.

Maybe I'm not fully understanding how this works but it seems that apps like Postman circumvent this somehow. Whereas when I'm trying to access the api from a local file in my browser I bump into this problem.
Do I need to host the webpage I'm calling from to get this to work? Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler to determine any differences in the working and noon working pass through? or looked for that header in the outgoing from postman?

Comment: Take a look here https://enable-cors.org/index.html

Comment: @vipersassassin It seems no GET request was sent in the code. That's odd.

Comment: @Kostis Is this done in a .js file? I don't have access to the implementation details.

Comment: @Jesper it's a security feature...if you perform requests from another domain you have to configure the API to accept requests from that domain

Comment: Yes I know. What I'm saying is I probably don't have access to the configuring part. Is this setup in a .js file or .yml file or something completely different? And any idea how Postman works around this issue?

Comment: @Jesper Postman does not workaround it, since it issues HTTP request directly and visibly. The CORS check is done by the browser when code outside the user control/visibilty issues HTTP requests.

Comment: @GiovanniLovato So the problem is that it's called through a browser?

Comment: @Jesper Yes, it's the browser applying a security measure to avoid malicious requests sent without the user consent; Postman does not need that check. See my answer for more details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser issues a `XMLHTTPRequest`, it checks if the *origin* (i.e. the domain) of that request is allowed by the endpoint to send requests. The check is done by a *preflight request*, i.e. a HTTP `OPTIONS` request which should provide a response containing a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the domain originating the request (or `*` to allow all domains).

Since this is a security measure of the browser, mainly based on the fact that browsing web pages the user may not know which requests are sent to which endpoints, Postman simply does not need to apply it because its requests are explicitly sent by the user himself.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request